# How to get the response?

Tags: jquery, api, response

My problem would be that I make a POST request with jQuery, and if there is an error I modify the HTTP status to for example 401 and echo the error. (I'm using $.ajax();) So, the problem is that I don't know how to print out that error message.

If I check it in firebug I get something like this: `{"*THE URL OF THE FILE*":{"rc":401,"body":"*error message*"}}`

Can anybody tell me that how to print that error message out? (For example with alert();)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a difference between $.post and $.ajax... $.ajax includes both a success and error callback option where as $.post only has the success function. Read [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) for more info...

With that said, maybe the $.ajax would be a better fit to capture the error?  Here is an example from the [jQuery site](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) on how this is done.

```
$.ajax({
          url: "script.php",
          global: false,
          type: "POST",
          data: ({id : this.getAttribute('id')}),
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(){
             //Happy Path...
          },
          error: function(msg){
             alert(msg.status);
          }
       };
```

Take a look at the "error: function(msg)"...

Comment: I've tried this one, and the response in this case is an object.

Comment: It contains the type of request, the url, data etc. But there is no response in it : /

Comment: That's right, the response is XMLHttpRequest object, and you can check HTTP-status using a corresponding property. It'd be msg.status, in terms of example above.

Comment: No problem, there is a property for that too. Try msg.statusText.

Comment: msg.responseText is that I was looking for. Thanks for your help. : )

Answer (score 0):

In error function you can use simply like

```
error: function(err){
             alert(err.responseText);
          }
```

Here `responseText` will give you the exact error message where you have been missing.